# Unity 2D Character Movement

Tags: game-physics, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

For the game I'm trying to build, I want my player objects to move when 'W/A/S/D' are held down.

For example, if I wanted to move right, I'd have to hold down 'D'.

I've tried using Rigidbody2D.AddForce, but I dislike the feel of the movement it creates.

I'm looking for instant movement and stopping, as opposed to any acceleration/decceleration.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!!
Alex

Comment: Try looking into `transform.position`

Comment: TY :D yeah i got it thanks to greenPadawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.
In the update method, fetch the movement values from WASD keys using the following code.

```
MovementInputValue = Input.GetAxis ("VerticalAxis_name");
TurnInputValue = Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalAxis_name");
```

Then, in the FixedUpdate method, move the object with the following code.

```
// For moving

    Vector3 movement = transform.forward * MovementInputValue * m_Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + movement);

 //For turning
    float turn = TurnInputValue * m_TurnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    Quaternion turnRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0f, turn, 0f);
    rigidbody.MoveRotation (rigidbody.rotation * turnRotation);
```

This code is written for 3D movement, but you can easily change it to 2D

Comment: Dude thank you!! That's exactly the movement I'm looking for :D, thanks a ton, Alex